# How Do I Specify Fallback to Monospace in Weasyprint

Tags: html, css, pdf, font-family, weasyprint

How do I specify that weasyprint should fall back to using a monospace font when rendering text in <pre> tags?

I'm converting an HTML document to PDF using weasyprint. The document has some text that I tag with <pre>. I specify the fixed-width font "Consolas" for this text, but if Consolas isn't available on the system, I want to fall back to a generic monospace font.

However, if I specify "monospace" in the CSS, weasyprint doesn't render the text in monospace at all. I suspect this might be a bug, but wanted to see if I just wasn't doing this correctly.

In the example below, "Some code text" is rendered in a proportional font, whereas "Some text code" is rendered in a fixed-width font.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <pre style="font-family: Consolas, monospace; font-size: 3em">
    Some code text
    </pre>
    <pre style="font-family: Consolas; font-size: 3em">
    Some text code 
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding on GitHub: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/158

By the way, I do not usually watch StackOverflow for WeasyPrint question. Writing to WeasyPrint’s mailing list or issue tracker will get more response.